# Inserting multiple rows with PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert multiple rows using transaction-bind through PHP PDO.  Below is my code.

```
$arrkeys = array_keys($this->postItem);
$itemqry = "INSERT INTO test_item (itemdate, flditmname, fieldtype, subscribe, id, year) VALUES (:itemdate, :flditmname, :fieldtype, :subscribe, :id, :year);" // dynamically generated

$itmstmt = $dbcon->prepare($itemqry);

for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++){
  foreach ($arrkeys as $key){
     $val = $this->postItem[substr($key,1)][$i];
     $itmstmt->bindParam($key, $val);
  }

  try {
    $itmstmt->execute();
  } catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}
```

I verified the values are populating correctly (for the bind) as follows :

```
echo $key."=".$val."<br>";  //echoed just before the bind.

:itemdate=2012-07-02 15:09:04
:flditmname=dccd
:fieldtype=2
:subscribe=X
:id=12345
:year=2012
:itemdate=2012-07-12 15:09:19
:flditmname=lkpok
:fieldtype=3
:subscribe=X
:id=12345
:year=2012
```

However, after inserting in my db table, all fields of all rows are taking the value '2012' (the value of last field).

I get no clue why this is happening. Can anyone help me track the issue?  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `bindParam` takes *a reference to a variable* as its argument, `bindValue` takes *the value of a variable* as its argument. The way you did it, you gave it multiple references to the same variable `$val`, which will of course all evaluate to the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong method:

```
$itmstmt->bindParam($key, $val);
```

Should be:

```
$itmstmt->bindValue($key, $val);
```

[`bindValue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) binds a value to a parameter, whereas
[`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) binds a parameter to the specified variable name

Comment: Sometimes we miss those simple things that make the most difference in our lives. Thank you both for your ultra fast responses.  You saved my day.